# не знаю почему выдает undefined

Tags: javascript

когда вызываю row оно вдает "Input rown undefined"

```js
let game = {
  pleyer: "x",
  board: board = [
    ["_", "_", "_"],
    ["_", "_", "_"],
    ["_", "_", "_"]
  ],

  boardStr: alert(this.board[0].join(" ") + "\n" + this.board[1].join(" ") + "\n" + this.board[2].join(" ")),
  winningCombinations: [
    [
      [0, 0],
      [0, 1],
      [0, 2]
    ],
    [
      [2, 0],
      [2, 1],
      [2, 2]
    ],
    [
      [1, 0],
      [1, 1],
      [1, 2]
    ],

    [
      [0, 0],
      [1, 1],
      [2, 2]
    ],
    [
      [0, 2],
      [1, 1],
      [2, 0]
    ],

    [
      [0, 0],
      [1, 0],
      [2, 0]
    ],
    [
      [0, 2],
      [1, 2],
      [2, 2]
    ],
    [
      [0, 1],
      [1, 1],
      [2, 1]
    ]
  ],

  row: +prompt("Input rown \n\n" + this.boardStr),
  colum: +prompt("Input column \n\n" + this.boardStr)
}

while (true) {
  game.boardStr();
  let row = game.row();
  let column = game.colum();
  if (board[row][column] !== "_") {
    alert("Wrong step. Try another one.");
  }
}
```

Comment: `alert` ничего не возвращает

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном коде несколько недочетов:

1. неявное объявление переменной `board`:

   ```
   board: board = [
   ```

   здесь, перед инициализацией поля `board` создается глобальная переменная с тем же именем, которой так же присваивается массив.
2. Попытка присвоить свойству результат выполнения функции `alert`

   ```
   boardStr: alert(this.board[0].join(" ")
   ```

   так как `alert` ничего не возвращает, значением поля становится `undefined`.
3. Попытка обратиться к объекту до его создания:

   ```
   boardStr: alert(this.board[0].join(" ")
   ```

   внутри литерала объекта, нельзя сослаться на сам объект с помощью `this`, в данном случае `this` будет глобальным объектом. И, так как, в первом пункте указано, что создалась глобальная переменная `board`, здесь идет к ней обращение.
4. Нет определенности чем должно быть поле `boardStr`. Исходя из названия, это должна быть строка, исходя и способов применения

   ```
   "Input rown \n\n" + this.boardStr
   ```

   это все еще строка, или

   ```
   game.boardStr();
   ```

   функция
5. Аналогично 4 пункту, но для свойств `row`, `col`: данные поля используются и как функции и как числа/строки

Для исправления первых двух пунктов, достаточно убрать лишнее и

```
board: [
```

и использовать функцию, которая вернет строку с текущим состоянием:

```
boardStr: function() { return (this.board[0].join(" ") + "\n" + this.board[1].join(" ") + "\n" + this.board[2].join(" "))},
```

Для решения остальных недочетов, необходимо определиться, с тем, как будут использоваться указанные поля и исходя из этого исправить код.